# Django doesn't see static files (404 error)

Tags: python, css, django, frontend

I was faced with a problem when django can't see static files and I'm getting 404 error every time visiting the page.

```
[05/Oct/2021 19:25:07] "GET /static/main/css/index.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1813
```

Here is my setting.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )

# Default primary key field type
```

Another part was cut

HTML file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'main/css/index.css' %}" />
</head>
```

Another part was cut too

[My files (png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XujTg.png)

Comment: did you `serve` media in urls?

Comment: Do you need to add `BASE_DIR` to the entry in `STATICFILES_DIRS`? Something like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: Can you share the `urls.py` where you added the views to access the static files? Is `DEBUG` set to `True`?

Comment: DEBUG is True @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('about', views.about)
]

Comment: @IainShelvington How can i do it?

Comment: @HamidrezaKhorammfar No

Comment: @goozzy: you need to add the static views to your `urls.py`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your application's `urls.py`

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)/$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}, name = 'media'),
```

do not forget to import this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
```

your settings should be like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_URL = '/media/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'media/static', ) 

STATIC_ROOT = 'media/staticfiles/'
```

Comment: Do I need to change folders in any way?

Comment: @goozzy you just have to create a `media` folder in project folder and create a `static` folder in media folder

Comment: Still doesn't work. 
-I pasted first part of code in `urls.py` in array of links
-pasted second part in `urls.py`
-changed values in `settings.py` and pasted parts which weren't there

Comment: did you change the `href` of `link` in html files for css files? to `href='{% static "css/index.css" %}'` ?

Answer (score 0):

add this in you main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve


from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in you settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'templates'
STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'static'

and in the bottom of you settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_CDN
```

this has to work for you and tell me if still the issue is not solve and update your question what you tried

Comment: STATIC_CDN is not defined

Comment: STATIC_CDN = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles' add this in your settings.py to and create a folder name "staticfiles" in  where mange.py is this will solve you problem

Comment: @goozzy did this work for you or not?

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was solved by creating new project and follow usual steps.

Answer (score -2):

IDK what was an issue, but i solved it by creating new project and using virtual environment. All static files are visible now.

My code now:

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        BASE_DIR / "static"
    ]
```

index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/style_index.css' %}"/>
</head>
</html>
```

**Folder structure**

[image: Folder structure]